# Perl search and replace NOT working

Tags: regex, windows, perl

I am trying to replace a string in a file but my procedure seems to be removing the string and not replacing it with what I want

Example

```
perl -ne 'print unless s/ServerIp=${Solid.host}/ads/;' needsToBeReplaced.prp > blah.txt
```

will remove

"ServerIp=${Solid.host}" and just leave the line blank instead of printing "ads" in its place

I am running in Windows by the way. Also I have no 3rd parameter in the regex because I only want to change the first occurrence.  I have also tried

```
perl -pi -e 's/ServerPort=${Solid.port}/ads/;' needsToBeReplaced.txt
```

but I get permission errors so editing in place is a no go

Comment: Trust me, Perl search and replace works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You print the line only if the substitution is not successful. If you want to print always, do not use `unless`:

```
perl -pe "s/ServerIp=\${Solid.host}/ads/;" needsToBeReplaced.prp > blah.txt
```

You should also escape the dollar sign to prevent its interpretation by Perl.

Also note that double quotes must be used on MS Windows.

Comment: You should also escape the dollar sign to prevent its interpolation by the substitution operator. Almost surely the OP means to use `${Solid.host}` as a literal string, and not as a reference to the value of the variable `$Solidhost`.

Comment: @mob: That was what I meant, but without a MSWindows box at hand, I might have used a wrong number of backslashes.

Comment: OMFG I'm an idiot. This is embarrassing haha...I deserve the downvotes. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

With what you've got now, if the substitute succeeds, it will return a true value, which means `unless` will be true, which means nothing will be printed.  You could do it like this:

```
perl -ne 's/ServerIp=${Solid.host}/ads/; print;' needsToBeReplaced.prp > blah.txt
```